# Kotlin - Can not access <uses-permision> in AndroidManifest file to make permission request

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to request permission to use the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but when I add them to the `AndroidManifest` file like so, I am not able to call them from my activity when I go to request permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if I add the following request to my MainActivity I get an error on the names of the permissions:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                  arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), RQ_PERMISSION)
```

However, if I have them in the manifest like this, there is no error but the permissions don't get requested.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `import android.Manifest` or can use

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), RQ_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: Thank you for appreciation, May the force be with you!